# Inform user about cross domain redirection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to fire up a confirm box method upon a click of any anchor tag based link in my application if that redirects the user to a different domain.

So lets suppose I am using https://test.com and I click on a anchor tag based link

```
<a onclick='window.open('https://www.google.co.in','_blank')>Click Me</a>
```

Then I need to fire up a custom confirmation popup method which if user confirms it redirects the user to the mentioned link.

Edit: I would like to keep my anchor tag the way it is above. Is there some way I can capture this event and then fire up my method.

Comment: I added an answer below, as it's quite simple and quick. But if you ask more questions in future, especially with something a bit more complicated, please note that people generally expect you to show some effort of your own to try and research and solve the problem yourself, and then we would help you with the specific problem in the code you've tried. This isn't really a free write-my-code service, it should be a collaboration. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info. Just something to bear in mind, if you don't want downvotes and close-question votes in future :-).

Answer (score 2):

You could do with having a function which runs on the "onclick" event, which then contains the code which pops up the "confirm" box.

Demo:

```js
function openWindowWithConfirm(url) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to go to " + url + "?")) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick='openWindowWithConfirm("https://www.google.co.in")'>Click Me</a>
```

P.S. Terminology note: opening a new window is not the same as "redirection". A redirect is actually normally a term for a header sent out by the server in response to a request, telling the browser to go somewhere else instead. But people sometimes use it to mean doing a client-side navigation of the current window to a new URL. Certainly though, opening a *new* window doesn't redirect anything - the existing window stays on the same page.

Comment: I understand your solution and have already tried and used it, but my problem is that I am not planning to change the existing onclick method i.e. onclick='window.open('https://www.google.co.in','_blank') that I wrote in the anchor tag....So that is the reason I asked that if I keep it the way I mentioned above, is there some way I still can manage a confirm popup.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you don't change the onclick functionality, how can you expect to change the behaviour which happens when you click? There's no magic override. It's simple logic - if you want control what happens when the user clicks on the link, you have to change the code which runs when the user clicks on the link. Why don't you want to change it?

Comment: I feel this is an apt solution where we can provide an override for window.open                `window.open = function(url,target){  //Functional requirements}`

Comment: I personally don't think overriding built-in functions is a great idea, because you till have to then replace the functionality which actually opens the window (and I'm not sure the source for it is available, I suspect it's a call to a native function in the browser really) but I suppose you _could_ do that if you really want.